# Payoff table for a top (short) straddle

Tags: finance

Is the following table for a short (top) straddle correct?

$K\equiv \text{Strike price}$

$S_T\equiv \text{Stock price at time T}$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{Range of} & \text{Payoff} & \text{Payoff} & \text{Total}\\
\text{stock price} & \text{from call} & \text{from put} & \text{payoff}\\
\hline
S_T\le K & S_T-K & 0 & S_T-K\\
S_T\gt K & 0 & K-S_T & K-S_T
\end{array}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you lose $S_T-K$ on the short call when $S_T >K$ and lose $K-S_T$ on the short put when $S_T<K.$ The total payoff can be written more compactly as $-|S_T-K|.$